# Swig JavaScript C++ arguments handling

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, swig, v8

I'm trying to wrap Box2D (C++ game physics engine) as Node.js native addon (GitHub: [box2d-native](https://github.com/zuker/box2d-native)). But unfortunately I don't know C++.

There are couple of methods that requires objects of abstract class, i.e.:

```
void SetDebugDraw(b2Draw* debugDraw);
```

Since `b2Draw` has pure virtual methods it can't be instantiated. I've tried to create class inherited from `b2Draw` with non-pure virtual methods, but there is no possibility to override those methods in JS.
Also I've tried to create Swig input typemap for `b2Draw*`, but I do not understand how to convert `v8::Object` to `b2Draw*` or any other C++ type using Swig helpers.
So I need an advise how to create typemap or how to override C++ class methods in JS.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you might be going at this the wrong way?

For objects that cannot be instantiated you should create a 'puppet' wrapper object. The b2Draw argument would never be sent to JavaScript as a variable, but it could be manipulated through JavaScript in C++ space - just like how any wooden puppet would be manipulated.

Comment: Thanks! Seems reasonable, but then I need to create wooden puppets for all abstract class arguments and even some kind of wooden puppets factory (for example, to create instances of `b2ContactListener`), right?

Comment: I completely spaced the concept of abstract classes when reading your question. Abstract classes cannot be instantiated but they can be inherited. My suggestions then would be to create a new class that inherits b2Draw, wrap that class, and maybe consider using function callbacks: https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html